# How to setup jsp Pages on a Webserver

Tags: html, jsp, server, webserver

I would like to set up a webserver to improve my skills and further my education. My problem right now is that I can only access HTML pages. When I create an intex.jsp and put it on the webserver, the jsp page does not appear, but a forbidden page. If I link the jsp page via the HTML page, only the text of the document appears. What is the reason for this and how can I work around it so that I can also work with dynamic web pages?

I've never worked in practice before, only in theory so far, so I don't have much idea.

Comment: No, a webserver can only handle HTML files. For JSP files you need to use a JSP/servlet container, such as Tomcat or Jersey. They are lightweit and simple for learning purposes. HTML is a text file which contains tags interpreted by the browser when a page is loaded. JSP has also tags but they are handled on the server before the page is returned back to the browser. What is JSP? How to create a Dynamic Web Project you might find from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73804816/573032) answer.